# Cucumber java - Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<Cucumber> to Class<? extends Runner> error in test runner

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

i am trying to setup cucumber framework using java to run my tests but i am getting type mismatch error in Test Runner.

```
package cucumbertest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "Feature", 
    glue={"stepDefinition"}
)

public class TestRunner {
}
```

This is my code

Comment: Can you add the exception stacktrace?

Comment: I have not run it yet as i am getting mismatch error

Comment: Make sure that you have correct dependencies defined in your project:

`<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>`

https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm#junit-runner - more info on basic set up

Answer (score 0):

Try with these configurations:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.learnautomation.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>com.learnautomation.cucumber</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>  

<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
```